# Regular expression in django url

Tags: django

In Django 1.7, how can I create **only one** url regex which matches **all** 3 following templates:

> 1. /page/
> 2. /page/{two characters}/
> 3. /page.html

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
url(r'^/page(\/\w{2}\/|\/|\.html)$', yourview)
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^page/$', yourviews.page),
   url(r'^page/(\w{2})/$', yourviews.page_detail),
   url(r'^page.html$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="page.html")),
)
```

**UPDATE**: I added `TemplateView` for your `page.html`, so you dont need to write views for it. this is one of the beauties of Django.

Comment: I edited my question, do you have any suggestion for only one url which matches all three urls?

Answer (score 1):

urls.py

```
url(r'^page/$', views.page),
url(r'^page/(\w{2})/$', views.page),
url(r'^page\\.html$', views.page),
```

views.py

```
def page(request, two_chars=''):
    # ...
```

See [this doc link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#specifying-defaults-for-view-arguments).